# Java help - illegal start to expression/class expected

Tags: arrays, object, constructor

```
public class Ship
{

public static int[] size = {3, 2, 3, 5, 4};                                                                    
public static String[] shipNames = {"Destroyer", "Cruiser", "Submarine",
                                      "Aircraft Carrier", "Battleship"};   

public Ship(String shipNames[], int size[])
  {
    this.shipNames[] = shipNames[];
    this.size[] = size[];
  }

}
```

Okay so basically what I'm trying to do is make it so my constructor repeats two static variables...

In another class, I'm calling this object Ship...

```
newShip = new Ship(Ship.shipNames[i],Ship.size[i]);
```

But when it sends I get these error messages:

```
Error: illegal start of expression
Error: '.class' expected 
Error: illegal start of expression
Error: '.class' expected
```

Working with arrays is quite confusing for a beginner such as myself. :(

Comment: The Java compiler will usually tell you which source line number the errors occur on. What line number do the error messages indicate, and which line of your source code is that?

Comment: you are declaring class variables instead of instance variables by using the keyword `static`. There are still some other mistakes. See someone's answer below

Answer (score 1):

There are many things wrong here.

1. When you write something like `String shipNames[]`, the `[]` is **not** part of the variable name. It is part of the variable **type**. So when you are just using the variable, you are not supposed to write them.
2. You declared the constructor to accept arrays, but you are trying to pass single values to it. Which do you actually want to happen?
3. When you refer to `this.shipNames`, presumably you mean to set some field of the object you're constructing. But you have not defined such a field. You already have a thing named `shipNames` in the class, but it's `static` - it's part of the class, not the instances.

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems with your code.

First is that your are passing the constructor a string and an int, not an array of strings or array of ints here:

```
newShip = new Ship(Ship.shipNames[i],Ship.size[i]);
```

Secondly, you need to receive a string and an int in the constructor, as follows:

```
public String shipName; 
public int size;
public Ship(String shipName, int size)
  {
    this.shipName = shipName;
    this.size = size;
  }
```

There might be other syntax and semantic errors too, but those seem to be the most obvious ones to me.